# Adobe Air - Copy image to clipboard

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, clipboard

I'm tying to modify [this Air copy and paste tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/quickstart/articles/scrappy_copy_paste.html) from Adobe. 
How to copy an image to clipboard via keyboard *Ctrl+C* without selecting it first? (The example needs a click in the image before that works)

This is the related code: http://pastebin.com/geTPPwFd

Thanks
Uli

Comment: Probably not possible - all copy/paste I've seen requires user action.

Comment: I've edited my question. There is a source code available that shows that it works. (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/quickstart/articles/scrappy_copy_paste.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(displayObject.width, displayObject.height);
bmpData.draw(displayObject);
Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData(ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT, bmpData);
```

More [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html#setData%28%29) and [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29).